# Applications of Integration: PDF

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

The probability of showing the first symptoms at various times during the quarantine
period is described by the probability density function:

```
f(t) = (t-5)(11-t) (1/36)
```

Find the probability that the symptoms will appear within 7 days of contact.

F(t) = (1/36)(8.t^2 -t^3/3 -55t)

P(x<7) = F(7) - F(0)

After taking the integral I equate t to 7 but that doesn't give me the right answer.

Expected answer is:  0.259

Comment: Show us your working. If this has positive support, you should be integrating on $[0, 7]$.

Comment: Edited. I tried the same but got a different result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is understood that that the denisty is $0$ for $x <5$ since you cannot have negative values for  the density. Hence the answer is $\int_5^{7} \frac {(t-5)(11-t)} {36}dt$ and this does work out to the approximate value $0.259$.

Comment: Thankyou! I get it now.